# Editing cookie from IE Addon

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, add-on, ieaddon

I am trying to create one addon using C#.net and SpicIE framework. I want to edit a cookie for a particular domain from my addon. I  want to read/write values to/from cookie. How can i do it?

Please help me if there is any way to edit a cookie for a domain.